# Ansible Error when using dict with csv: "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was 'dict object' has no attribute 'schema'

Tags: csv, ansible

I'm trying to get my playbook working with csv while using a dict due to the nature of the data [each task asks for different parts of the data in a row so i can't use a list?].
BD and EPG always will appear exactly once per file and can be used as a key if necessary.

I'm getting an error "the task includes an option with an undefined variable". Since the variable (schema) appears as a column header in the csv file I must have some sort of syntax issue.

What I am trying to do is loop, one row at a time, through the csv file and have schema: "{{ item.schema }}" evaluate to that particular rows value under the schema column, etc.

**Playbook:**

```
tasks:
      - name: Read CSV
        read_csv:
        # Name of the csv
         path: ./Create_EPGs_and_BDs.csv
         dialect: excel
         key: bd
        # Creates register value to be used later
        register: csv_data
    
    #
    ##################################################
    #Creates BD in MSO Template
    ##################################################
    #
      - name: Add a new BD
        cisco.mso.mso_schema_template_bd:
         <<: *aci_login
         state: present
         schema: "{{ item.schema }}"
         template: "{{ item.template }}"
         bd: "{{ item.bd }}"
         vrf:
            name: "{{ item.vrf }}"
        loop: "{{ csv_data.dict|dict2items }}"
    
    #
    ##################################################
    #Creates EPG in MSO Template
    ##################################################
    #
      - name: Add a new EPG
        cisco.mso.mso_schema_template_anp_epg:
         <<: *aci_login
         state: present
         schema: "{{ item.schema }}"
         template: "{{ item.template }}"
         anp: "{{ item.app_profile }}"
         epg: "{{ item.epg }}"
         bd:
          name: "{{ item.bd }}"
        loop: "{{ csv_data.dict|dict2items }}"
```

**CSV File:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlyLP.jpg

What is the correct syntax to pull the csv values for the entire row and then let me access each column's value in the playbook for that particular row?

Comment: Please don't post images of text (or links to images of text). Just include the data in your question, [formatted as a table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dict2items` is going to transpose your `dict` into a list of dicts, shaped like `[{"key": "the-value-of-bd-for-that-row", "value": {"schema": "schema1", ...}}, ...]`

Thus, you just need to add `.value` in between your `item` and the dict key it references:

```yaml
      - name: Add a new BD
        cisco.mso.mso_schema_template_bd:
         <<: *aci_login
         state: present
         schema: "{{ item.value.schema }}"
         template: "{{ item.value.template }}"
         # or if prefer, item.value.bd
         bd: "{{ item.key }}"
         vrf:
            name: "{{ item.value.vrf }}"
        loop: "{{ csv_data.dict|dict2items }}"
```

*it's your code style, but you'll want to be very careful using only one space for yaml indentation, as it's very easy to make a mistake doing that, and certainly makes asking questions on SO harder by doing so :-)*

---

In the future, the use of `debug: var=item` will go a long way toward helping you understand the shape of your data when you encounter any such "has no attribute" error

Comment: Really appreciate the insight into the datastructure, that's what i was missing. It all works now, thank you!